# create simple form with AngularJS+Bootstrap+grid

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on AngularJS and Bootstrap. I am new to both. I wanted to create one form which include **firstname** input textbox,**lastname** input textbox , **city** dropdown and add button called **addUser**.

When I click the add user button it should be saved in our database and then displayed in below grid with edit and delete button. When I click the edit button, all record comes under above corresponding textbox. I have gone through below link but i didn't get my scenario implementation, in that they used xeditable.

```
http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an form example made with angular [link](https://github.com/brettshollenberger/Angular-Simple-Form)

Basicly you need to create a **controller**. In your controller create a user object, bind this object properties to form contollers with **ng-model**. When user clicks a button send user object to a method in your controller, add **ng-click** to your buttons. In your functions, you can do create, edit, delete actions.

Please refer the link and check the highlighted keywords, this must cover all of your needs.

Comment: i have downloaded mentioned url.but i didn't get solution file to open this sample.pls suggest ?what about grid?

Comment: For grid, you can use ng-repeat to repeat every column so you can create your own grid or you can use other libraries such as gridmvc.